# GnuPG::Interface fails to install on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, perl, cpan, request-tracker

I'm trying to install a CentOS 7 server to run Request Tracker. By running `make testdeps` I can see all missing packages and `make fixdeps` is supposed to install this packages. There is one package that I can't install (`GnuPG::Interface`). This package is used by Perl.

I already tried to install it by `cpan install GnuPG::Interface` and `cpan install GnuPG::Interface --force`, but everytime I get an error message saying:

```
Can't locate Fatal.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ./t /root/.cpan/build/GnuPG-Interface-0.51-CdOOe3/inc
/root/.cpan/build/GnuPG-Interface-0.51-CdOOe3/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/GnuPG-Interface-0.51-    
CdOOe3/blib/arch /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /root/.cpan/build/GnuPG
-Interface-0.51-CdOOe3/blib/lib/GnuPG/Interface.pm line 23.
```

I've tried to run `yum install perl-Test-Fatal`, but even after the installation process the error keep coming. The same happens if I try to install using `cpan`.

Comment: Verify that `GnuPG::Interface` works with gpg 2, which CentOS 7 ships with.

Comment: Does the package not get installed by fixdeps and if not what error info shows up there?

Comment: @djhaskin987 I'm sorry, but maybe because my english I couldn't understand what you tried to mean... If you are asking to me to verify if gpg 2 is installed the answer is yes. I have the following packages installed: `gpgme.x86_64, libgpg-error.x86_64 and pygpgme.x86_64`

Comment: @Ram The error I pasted on first post is from fixdeps. After that, the installation runs through the rest of the process and exits the installation.

Comment: @Leandro_GS I only meant that there are two versions of gpg which are currently used: version 1 and version 2. Some programs are not compatible with version 2. However, looking at your output again, I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @djhaskin987 I'll do a fresh install of CentOS 7. Maybe it is some configuration I've made somewhere...

Answer (score 6):

I too am installing RT in CentOS7, and solved as following.

execute `cpan install -f GnuPG::Interface` instead of `cpan install GnuPG::Interface --force`
then do `cpan install Fatal` (I'd run `yum install perl-Test-Fatal` as well)

in addition `yum install expat-devel` had also executed when `make testdeps` told "XML::RSS >= 1.05 ...MISSING". After this `make testdeps` succeeded beautifully.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; `cpan install -f GnuPG::Interface` resolved this for me on regarding my RT installation.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me and I am also trying to install Request Tracker 5. `cpan install -f GnuPG::Interface` did the trick when force, `--force`, and no `force` at all would not work. Thanks.